# How do I limit the move to one div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a modal window that is generated via code I cannot alter. This modal window has the close button in the top right of the screen. I need to take that close button and move the container to the container for the modal content so that I can position the button within the content window, not the overlay.

I wrote some jQuery to move the element and it does that and puts it where I want, the problem I'm having is that it's moving all of the close buttons from all of the modals to all of the modals.

How do I limit the move to only one div that has the close button so that I don't have multiple close buttons in each modal window?

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".ult-overlay").ready(function() {
        jQuery(".ult-overlay-close").appendTo(".ult_modal-content");
    });
});
```

HTML before execution:

```
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
```

HTML after execution:

```
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
 <div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help given!

Comment: try this: `$(this).find(".ult-overlay-close").appendTo($(this).find(".ult_modal-content"));`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That did not work, nothing happened to the close div, it stayed in the original position.

Comment: yes, just seen that you used `(".ult-overlay").ready` instead of `(".ult-overlay").each`. So `this` was not good. No need to use ready here if your html is fixed because you are in `$(document).ready`. Corrected version with `jQuery` instead of `$` will work in a `each`: `jQuery(this).find(".ult-overlay-close").appendTo(jQuery(this).find(".ult_modal-content"));`

Comment: note: grafix777's answer is perfectly valid if your structure doesn't change. Just wanted to show that you can do it also by finding certain classes in given cantainers too

Comment: I tried it with `each` instead of `ready` and it still does not work.

Comment: well it works perfectly here, on various browsers, i won't argue but it should work (beware of you classes syntax though, some are prefixed `ult-` and other `ult_`, dunno if intended)

Comment: This is the code I'm using and it's not working. 
 `jQuery(".ult-overlay").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).find(".ult-overlay-close").appendTo(jQuery(this).find(".u‌​lt_modal-content"));
 });`

Comment: you should verify in your browser code (on chrome for ex), i had the problem first when i copied/paste your code and it was not working: there are hidden characters in it (shows as red dots in the browser code). These are the guilty ones, not the code ;)

Comment: I got pulled into another task for a little bit. I'll check this out shortly. Thank you very much. I will reply to let you know if I got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code is helpful for you:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.move').click(function () {
    $('.ult-overlay-close').each((index, item) => {
      $(item).appendTo($(item).prev())
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.ult_modal-content {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
<div class="ult-overlay">
    <div class="ult_modal-content">
    </div>
    <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
</div>
<button type='button' class='move'>move</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much! That helped me out a ton. This is how I'm using it:

Comment: That helped me out a ton. This is how I'm using it:

<!-- language: lang-js -->

 `jQuery(".ult-overlay").ready(function() {
  jQuery('.ult-overlay-close').each((index, item) => {
   jQuery(item).appendTo(jQuery(item).prev())
  })
 });`

How would I move it to another container inside ult_modal-content?

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="ult-overlay">
        <div class="ult_modal-content">
            <div class="close-button-goes-here">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ult-overlay-close">Close</div>
    </div>